# ¿ Se puede instalar dos versiones diferentes de una base de datos MySql en un mismo ordenador?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

¿Se puede instalar una base de datos MySql versión (5.7.20.0) en una pc que tiene  ya instalado un servidor wampserver que viene por defecto con  una base de datos  Mysql versión (5.7.19)?.O
Osea, ¿se puede instalar dos versiones diferentes de una base de datos MySql en un mismo ordenador? .

Comment: Si podrias. He mirado y hay varias formas. Da una [vuelta por google](https://www.google.es/search?q=%C2%BF+se+pueden+instalar+dos+versiones+de+MySql+en+el+mismo+pc+?&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjon6Ct26vZAhWBGRQKHVFoDyoQBQglKAA&biw=1366&bih=637) y elige la que más se te adapte. Espero encuentres solucion.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

Sí, sólo hay que tomar en cuenta cuatro factores importantes uno es el nombre del servicio, segundo la ruta de instalación de archivos y librerías, tercero las variables de entorno y el último el número del puerto en el que escucha MySQL.

1. Es más fácil administrar un programa que se ejecuta en background en Windows si esta enlistado como servicio, al instalar el servicio deberás poner un nombre único al servicio de cada instalación.
2. La ruta de instalación de archivos y librerías, en general me refiero a la instalación del servidor y a los archivos donde se guardan las bases de datos, tendrías que buscar que no sean los mismos, generalmente MySQL se instala hasta incluyendo la versión en la carpeta de instalación en tu caso si necesitarías cambiar el nombre.
3. En las variables del entorno en el valor del PATH generalmente se agrega la carpeta de MySQL al momento de instalar, para cuando abras una consola y escribas el comando "mysql -u root" te intente abrir la conexión, por lo que deberás de tener cuidado a que comandos te estas refiriendo al ejecutarlos si son de una instalación o de la otra.
4. El puerto donde escucha MySQL generalmente es el 3306 pero si quieres ejecutar ambas bases de datos al mismo tiempo tendrías que asignarle un puerto diferente a cada instalación en el archivo my.cnf.

Creo que generalmente esos cuatro puntos son los más importantes a considerar, no sería muy recomendable tener las dos bases de datos corriendo por que gastaría muchos recursos de tu computadora, recomendaría tener sólo una prendida. En mi computadora de hecho, tengo dos versiones diferentes de MySQL una 5.0 de 32 bits y otra de 5.7 de 64 bits, cada uno de estos cuatro puntos podrían ser mucho más extensos, te recomendaría si quieres profundizar hacerlos en otras preguntas y sobre la duda en eespecífico.

[image: Captura de pantalla de dos versiones]

Comment: Pero la verdad no veo el caso de instalar una versión 5.7.20 y otra de 5.7.19 casi son lo mismo, en mi caso las necesito por que uso características de la versión nueva que la versión vieja no tiene, y me da mucha flojera migrar las bases de datos montadas en la vieja  a la nueva, son más de 40 Gb.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda